# Location.hash equally option.value and set selected

Tags: jquery, select, hash, get, attr

I have url like this with id:

```
/montazh/#slide4
/montazh/#slide5
/montazh/#slide6
/montazh/#slide7
```

And i need get the location.hash, compare his with  select option value, and if two values equal set this value.attr("selected","selected").

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test option').filter(function() {
                return this.value && this.value == location.hash;
        }).prop('selected', true);
});

</script>
    <div class="styled-select">
        <select id="test" class="drop" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" size="1" name="Город">
            <option value="#slide0">Москва и область</option>
            <option value="#slide1">Рязань</option>
            <option value="#slide2">Казань</option>
            <option value="#slide3">Уфа</option>
            <option value="#slide4">Пермь</option>
            <option value="#slide5">Смоленск</option>
            <option value="#slide6">Екатеринбург</option>
            <option value="#slide7">Челябинск</option>
            <option value="#slide8">Краснодар</option>
            <option value="#slide9">Оренбург</option>
            <option value="#slide10">Набережные челны</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```